# Decimal Ternary Not Working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a ternary to assign a decimal type. It's not working for me. Am I going crazy?

Here's a screen shot of my debug. You can see the value of everything before I step.
[image]

And after I step here is the value. It isn't even one of the viable options (i.e. 1 or 2000).
[image]

Is there some strange limitation with decimals that I don't know about? When I break it out into its full if/else logical representation it works fine. The only thing I can guess is that I did recently install .NET Framework 4.5.

**UPDATE**

I've cleaned the solution and made sure I was running on code that was compiled in debug mode as recommended in the comments. Neither of those seemed to change anything.

I started to get curious though when I noticed all my unit tests were still passing. After a little more sleuthing I found that when I stepped one more time (i.e. stepped over memberItems.Add) price magically has the right value in it.

Does .Net do some kind of a delayed resolution of ternary operators similar to the yield command in iterator blocks? I've never noticed it before now but I don't know what else it could be. I suppose I could also still be running on code compiled in release mode accidentally. I've made dumber mistakes after triple checking myself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Look at my screen shots. I've pinned a few watch windows in them so you can see the values of my variables. Price is still 0 after I step.

Comment: Do a 'clean' and then rebuild.  Sometimes the debugging info gets out of sync with the actual executable's code.

Comment: Make sure that you are running in the debug mode, not in release mode. Also verify that the `price` that you pinned is not by mistake a member variable by the same name.

Comment: Good thoughts. I'm trying them now and will report soon.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight good one on pinning wrong variable. `price` should not be `0` on first screenshot, it is not initialized yet.

Comment: Alright, I'm still not sure what is going on, but here is what I know now. I cleaned the build and made sure I was in debug mode. Neither of those seemed to resolve the issue. However, when I step one more time (i.e. step over `memberItems.Add`) price magically has the right value. Does .Net do some kind of a delayed resolution of ternary operators similar to the `yield` command in iterator blocks? I've never noticed it before now but I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Best advice I can give you is **don't** use a ternary operator. Ternary is terse, confusing to most, hard to read and no more useful than a simple if then else.

Comment: @MichaelAllen In what world is it "best advice"? Ternary is created for cases similar to this one, it is by far the best tool for the job here.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev Thanks for your input. I think decimal is a C# value type and so by default has a value of zero according to MSDN. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - i would do this `decimal price = defaultPrice; if (shouldUseOverridePrice) { price = overridePrice; }`

Comment: I wonder if one of the objects has type `decimal?` instead of `decimal`.

Comment: @MarkRucker sorry, I was wrong (just verified by testing). I expected VS to produce "variable not in scope" message.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Many reasons why not to, my personal favourite: Try logging inside that ternary without turning it into an if statement. Also as said, if defaultPrice is really a default then `price = defaultPrice` should always happen. All you've done is introduce an opportunity for a bug.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev No problem. It was a good idea. I had to double check as well when I read your comment.

Comment: I faced same issue today, On two different machines I tried it, in first my ternary expression was not executed until variable was used(due to deferred execution), in second machine ternary expression was executed immediately without any deferred execution. Has anyone  found the cause/setting which is causing this deferred execution of ternary operator on some machines? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Impossible to diagnose code from a screenshot, so just a guess.

You cannot always *completely* rely on what a watch expression tells you.  The first possible failure mode is debugging code that was optimized.  A local variable like *price* will very typically be optimized by the jitter optimizer to be stored in a cpu register instead of the stack.  The watch expression will show you the stack location value, not the cpu register value.  With 0 being a common result.  The only real defense you have against this is only debugging code that was built by the Debug configuration.

Second failure mode is the way watch expressions are evaluated.  The CLR starts a dedicated thread when it detects an attached debugger.  The debugger can then use this thread to evaluate watch expressions.  This can go wrong if a variable has any thread affinity.  Common cases are variables that are [ThreadStatic] or are properties of COM objects.

Comment: I don't think any of the possible issues you mention would be relevant in my case but it is much more detail than I knew to begin with so thank you. Also just curious where you learned all this from? Any particular article or have you just picked it up over the years?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I also thought I was going crazy.

I found that changing my ASP.NET app to use "Visual Studio Developer Server" instead of IIS fixes it. Pity because I like using IIS as that's closer what's happening in production.